# How could conda environments have interfered with system installs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I (had) a system install of python 2.7, keras and tensorflow working fine.

Today I created some new conda environments, and installed several packages into the, including newer tensorflow versions.

All installs I did first activating the environment of interest, and using `conda install` and/or `pip install` INSIDE the environment (using pip whenever I previously did conda install pip inside said environment).

Now, for some reason, after deactivating all conda environments and being back at my system "environment" (no activated conda), I cannot import keras nor tensorflow any longer, both complaining about some module `"gast"` (see below for error messages).

This is baffling, as conda is not supposed to touch anything outside the environments. My python and modules are all outside conda.

`which pip, which spyder, which python` .. etc, all point to `/usr/bin`

What could have possibly gone wrong? And how can I repair the broken system modules?

My system installs of keras and tensorflow where done with pip. Could have conda's pip interfered with them?

```
pip show tensorflow-gpu


Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 1.14.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: grpcio, mock, keras-applications, enum34, tensorboard, wrapt, protobuf, keras-preprocessing, gast, wheel, numpy, termcolor, six, absl-py, tensorflow-estimator, google-pasta, backports.weakref, astor


pip show keras


Name: Keras
Version: 2.3.1
Summary: Deep Learning for humans
Home-page: https://github.com/keras-team/keras
Author: Francois Chollet
Author-email: francois.chollet@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: keras-applications, numpy, keras-preprocessing, scipy, h5py, pyyaml, six

>>> import tensorflow


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.standard_ops import *
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/standard_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import autograph
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.core.converter import ConversionOptions
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/core/converter.py", line 69, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.pyct import anno
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/anno.py", line 27, in <module>
    import gast
ImportError: No module named gast



import keras


Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.standard_ops import *
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/standard_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import autograph
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.core.converter import ConversionOptions
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/core/converter.py", line 69, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.pyct import anno
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/anno.py", line 27, in <module>
    import gast
ImportError: No module named gast
```

Comment: does it behave this way in a new shell?

Comment: yes. Also I can add that the tensorflow and keras installations where done with the system's pip

Comment: It says here (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment): "If there is an expectation to install software using pip along-side conda packages it is a good practice to do this installation into a purpose-built conda environment to protect other environments from any modifications that pip might make". So it shouldn't be pip fault

Comment: Could you try the same again by installing python >=3.5 version in your system. Please find the python installation reference [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package_location).